# Как происходит обновление базы данных при работе с Bitbucket

Tags: mysql, git, bitbucket

Всем привет, извините сразу, вопрос покажется странным или глупым.

Суть такова: раньше работали в основном с одним удаленным дев сервером, каждый по фтп, со своими задачами.

А сейчас удаленная работа, через git и bitbucket.

Каждый что-то делает, коммитит, а потом пушит.

И возникли вопросы:

как происходит обновление БД? например я дописал код, закомиттил, запушил. А потом все сделали пулл. Здесь понятно, у всех код одинаковый. А что касается бд? например что-то в mysql записалось, как это обновится у каждого участника?

и второй вопрос: пулл (обновление локальных репозиториев из общего проекта) долно происходит по команде тим лида? как это обычно принято? Спасибо.

Comment: Для базы данных обычно используется механизм версионирования через миграции

Answer (score 2):

***Как это обычно принято?***

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Одна общая база где-то в сети, куда все имеют доступ.
2. Дампы базы данных хранятся в каком-то big-data репозитории, например на том же Bitbucket.
3. Необходимые изменения, которые нужно внести в базу, описываются скриптами `INSERT TO ...` и хранятся в том же репозитории, либо в отдельном.